# Share backgrounds between Cucumber files?

Tags: background, cucumber

I have some Cucumber scenarios, for which I created the following files:

- create_extended_search.feature
- activate_extended_search.feature
- edit_extended_search.feature
- delete_extended_search.feature

Within these files, I have several scenarios.

Three of the files use the same background, and it would be nice to be able to place it into one file (e.g. `support/backgrounds.rb`) and then reference it from the feature files.

Is this possible somehow? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no notion of 'include'ing feature files in Cucumber.  As Justin points out, you can create a single step representing what you want as a background, and call that where appropriate.  An alternative is to use a Before hook to perform certain tasks in advance of scenarios that you mark with a specific tag.

Personally, I'd treat this problem as something of a red flag, and start asking if my feature files were split up in the best way possible.  Frequently if I find myself bemoaning the inability to include other feature files, or conversely, wishing I could exclude certain scenarios from running my background, it's a very strong sign that my feature files are too finely sliced up, or I'm trying to cram unrelated functionality together and need to split it up further.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable opinion. I will take another look at my feature files, you may be right with your assumption.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you would have to create a step that is made up of the steps in your current background. Then call that step in the background for each feature.

Comment: Thank you, this could be a solution, though not the expected/hoped one.